# Запрос к базе данных PostgreSQL на C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Пишу такой код:

```
NpgsqlConnection DBconnection = _dbconnection;
NpgsqlCommand DBcommand_1 = DBconnection.CreateCommand();
NpgsqlCommand DBcommand_2 = DBconnection.CreateCommand();
NpgsqlDataReader DataReader_1, DataReader_2;
DBcommand_1.CommandText = "SELECT Что-то там FROM Откуда-то";
DataReader_1 = DBcommand_1.ExecuteReader();
int fields = DataReader_1.FieldCount;
string[] product;
string code;
while (DataReader_1.Read())
{                   
    product = new string[fields + 3];
    product[0] = DataReader_1.GetInt32(0).ToString();
    code = DataReader_1.GetInt32(1).ToString();
    DBcommand_2.CommandText = "SELECT Что-то там FROM Откуда-то WHERE Код = " + code;
    DataReader_2 = DBcommand_2.ExecuteReader();
...
...
...
}
```

Во время выполнения второго запроса выдается ошибка: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."
Почему так, разве DBcommand_1 и DBcommand_2 как-то связаны? Если вместо Npgsql использовать OleDb, такой ошибки не возникает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй в строчку подключения прописать `MultipleActiveResultSets=true`

Если верить вот этому [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062192/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-c), то это связано с тем, что ты в рамках одного соединения выполняешь итерацию `DataReader'ом` и еще один какой-то запрос.

Если то, что выше не поможет, то запуск запроса в отдельном соединении точно должен помочь.

Comment: а как должна выглядеть строка подключения с MultipleActiveResultSets=true? Можно пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: У меня была такая строка "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=*************;Database=MyDataBase;", и куда я не добавлю "MultipleActiveResultSets=true" возникает ошибка: key=value argument incorrect in ConnectionString.